# UIactivitycontroller crash log

Tags: ios, crash-reports, uiactivityviewcontroller

I've submitted my app to apple and they've returned the following crash report. In their response they mention problems with the UIActivityViewController. I've try'd exporting nothing, a few items, and many items, and they all work for me. Here is the crash report, any insight as how to go about fixing my code will be greatly appreciated.

```
{"app_name":"My Movies","timestamp":"2016-11-09 09:31:21.24 -0800","app_version":"1.02","slice_uuid":"56a6e389-c77c-3d01-b158-506b66e410b2","adam_id":0,"build_version":"1.02","bundleID":"Kirk5291.MyMovies","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.1.1 (14B100)","incident_id":"FA447ABF-99C4-4874-8FA3-A40A91B5E882","name":"My Movies"}
Incident Identifier: FA447ABF-99C4-4874-8FA3-A40A91B5E882
CrashReporter Key:   a36779df2325372846e1db609ddeb937c42042f5
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             My Movies [1470]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/51E92E50-D3EE-431A-8D2F-C65D87B98175/My Movies.app/My Movies
Identifier:          Kirk5291.MyMovies
Version:             1.02 (1.02)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           Kirk5291.MyMovies [1004]


Date/Time:           2016-11-09 09:31:21.1881 -0800
Launch Time:         2016-11-09 09:31:18.4795 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.1.1 (14B100)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x18c3ce1c0 0x18ae0855c 0x192c57998 0x192572598 0x1925702e4 0x1924b3d5c 0x1924a5b10 0x192214854 0x18c37b7dc 0x18c37940c 0x18c37989c 0x18c2a8048 0x18dd2e198 0x19228d2fc 0x192288034 0x1000eba28 0x18b28c5b8)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b39e014 0x18b37f000 + 126996
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b466450 0x18b461000 + 21584
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018b3123e0 0x18b2af000 + 406496
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018addd2d4 0x18addc000 + 4820
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018adfacc0 0x18addc000 + 126144
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018ae08844 0x18ae00000 + 34884
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018adf766c 0x18addc000 + 112236
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018adf7234 0x18addc000 + 111156
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018ae0871c 0x18ae00000 + 34588
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c2a80bc 0x18c29f000 + 37052
10  GraphicsServices                0x000000018dd2e198 0x18dd22000 + 49560
11  UIKit                           0x000000019228d2fc 0x192212000 + 504572
12  UIKit                           0x0000000192288034 0x192212000 + 483380
13  My Movies                       0x00000001000eba28 0x1000e4000 + 31272
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018b28c5b8 0x18b288000 + 17848

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b39ea88 0x18b37f000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b46235c 0x18b461000 + 4956
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b461da4 0x18b461000 + 3492

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b461da0 0x18b461000 + 3488

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b39ea88 0x18b37f000 + 129672
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b462178 0x18b461000 + 4472
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b461da4 0x18b461000 + 3492

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b461da0 0x18b461000 + 3488

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b461da0 0x18b461000 + 3488

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b38016c 0x18b37f000 + 4460
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b37ffdc 0x18b37f000 + 4060
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c37bcec 0x18c29f000 + 904428
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c379908 0x18c29f000 + 895240
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c2a8048 0x18c29f000 + 36936
5   Foundation                      0x000000018cdb9a8c 0x18cdad000 + 51852
6   Foundation                      0x000000018cdda57c 0x18cdad000 + 185724
7   UIKit                           0x0000000192c02a2c 0x192212000 + 10422828
8   Foundation                      0x000000018ceb747c 0x18cdad000 + 1090684
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b464850 0x18b461000 + 14416
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b464760 0x18b461000 + 14176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b461dac 0x18b461000 + 3500

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b39e314 0x18b37f000 + 127764
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018b2bc23c 0x18b2af000 + 53820
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000018adcd994 0x18ad86000 + 293268
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000190b53384 0x19027c000 + 9270148
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000190b52484 0x19027c000 + 9266308
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000190b522c0 0x19027c000 + 9265856
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000190b52160 0x19027c000 + 9265504
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000190b53470 0x19027c000 + 9270384
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000190b5339c 0x19027c000 + 9270172
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000190b5364c 0x19027c000 + 9270860
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b464850 0x18b461000 + 14416
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b464760 0x18b461000 + 14176
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b461dac 0x18b461000 + 3500

Thread 8 name:  WebThread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b39de64 0x18b37f000 + 126564
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b467da4 0x18b461000 + 28068
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b467fa8 0x18b461000 + 28584
3   WebCore                         0x0000000190e53924 0x190deb000 + 428324
4   WebCore                         0x0000000190e53884 0x190deb000 + 428164
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c37b7dc 0x18c29f000 + 903132
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c37940c 0x18c29f000 + 893964
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c379a4c 0x18c29f000 + 895564
8   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c2a8048 0x18c29f000 + 36936
9   WebCore                         0x0000000190e5145c 0x190deb000 + 418908
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b464850 0x18b461000 + 14416
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b464760 0x18b461000 + 14176
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b461dac 0x18b461000 + 3500

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001702e83b7
x4: 0x000000018adfbbc3   x5: 0x000000016fd1b540   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000000010
x12: 0x000000018b329772  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000030000000300  x15: 0x0000000000000000
x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
x20: 0x00000001b0c1bc40  x21: 0x000000016fd1b540  x22: 0x00000001b0c22bb8  x23: 0x0000000000000001
x24: 0x0000000174200140  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
x28: 0x000000016fd1bbe0   fp: 0x000000016fd1b4a0   lr: 0x000000018b466450
sp: 0x000000016fd1b480   pc: 0x000000018b39e014 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: You first need to symbolicate the crash log so you can get more details from it.

Comment: Is there a website or something that'll show me how? I've tried by attaching my iPhone, then going to devices. I only get txt files from Apple, is there some other place I should be getting .crash files from?

Comment: What you posted is the crash file. Just remove the first line (from the opening to the closing curly braces).

Comment: Okay, I got it to work, Thanks!